# Hibernate/MySQL Connection Timeout

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I wrote a server-side application that powers a website and multiple mobile clients. I used Hibernate for data access. I later discovered that the app fails after a day! When I checked around online, I found out that its a well know issue with MySQL terminating a "stale" connection after 8 hours. In order to avoid this, I found many suggestions like including `?autoReconnect=true`, using `c3P0`, etc.
Since `autoReconnect` is officially discouraged (especially in production environment) and also because it didn't have any effect when I applied it, I decided to go for `c3p0`. Unfortunately, after introducing the `c3p0` configuration in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, the application starts throwing a `NullPointerException` somewhere in my code where I called `dbSession.close()`
This means that the `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()` actually returns `null`. I have added the required jars (c3p0-0.9.2-pre2.jar, hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar, hibernate-c3p0-3.3.2.GA.jar, mchange-commons-java-0.2.1.jar and c3p0-oracle-thin-extras-0.9.2-pre2.jar) even though I don't think its all of them that are required.
I've gone through many of the pages that talked about this issue but I'm still not able to set it up properly. Kindly help me with a "beginner-friendly" easy-to-implement, step-by-step procedure for setting up `c3p0` with Hibernate. I'm using Hibernate 3.3.6 on JDK 1.6, MySQL 5.5 and I'm developing in Netbeans 7.0.

Here is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/religion_app</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>

    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
    <property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>

    <!-- configuration pool via c3p0-->
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">120</property> <!-- seconds --> 
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">10</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">180</property> <!-- seconds -->
    <property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</property>

    <!--Mappings go here-->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is what I got after adding c3p0 (without slf4j):

```
    May 23, 2012 2:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet LoginChurch threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.processRequest(LoginChurch.java:109)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.doPost(LoginChurch.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

May 23, 2012 2:45:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet LoginChurch threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.<clinit>(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:23)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.processRequest(LoginChurch.java:68)
    at com.pacesolutions.religionapp.services.LoginChurch.doPost(LoginChurch.java:143)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.26 logs.
```

Most of my Hibernate configuration files where generated by Netbeans. I had the database on ground then I used the Hibernate wizards in Netbeans to generate the configuration files, entity classes and mapping files from it. These were working correctly before I introduced c3p0 (but they fail after 8 hours).
I use Mecurial with my project and reverting the whole project back to a time prior to when I introduced c3p0, it works again (for 8 hours). Even hand-deleting all the c3p0 configurations in hibernate.cfg.xml makes the app work again. *What could I be doing wrong?*

Comment: would you mind showing us the NPE's stacktrace as well as your patterns of working with the Hibernate (representative code samples basically)?

Answer (score 7):

The jars required for C3P0 configuration are *c3p0-0.9.2-pre2.jar* & *mchange-commons-java-0.2.1.jar*. Also, additionally you need to put *c3p0.properties* in classpath.

Below are the properties, which should be configured while using C3P0 with Hibernate.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">180</property>
```

**c3p0.properties**

- You can validate connection on each checkout `c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true`, but this is expensive operation.
- Else, you can retry to establish connection periodically.

  > c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts = 4
  >   c3p0.acquireRetryDelay = 5000

  This will retry 4 times with a delay of 5 seconds between each consecutive attempt.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please where do `c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts = 4` `c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=5000` go?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. May I ask what my HibernateUtil.java should look like?

Comment: @SayoStealth-virusOladeji Both these properties mentioned needs to be placed in c3p0.properties file. Probably, there is no effect to HibernateUtil.java, it is unaffected. You can try either `testConnectionOnCheckout` or these two properties.

Comment: My c3p0.properties file is now in the same directory with hibernate.cfg.xml and I still get the NullPointerException.

Comment: @SayoStealth-virusOladeji Edited hibernate.cfg.xml content, also try debugging further, is sessionFactory returning null or dbSession is null. These configuration files must be in project classpath

Comment: Thanks a lot! The fix works. The problem was due to an extra dependency of c3p0 itself (slf4j) that I didn't add and when I later did, I didn't add correctly. But everything is working perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

c3p0 has no dependency on SLF4J. If adding that library to your classpath fixed your issue, that is interesting, but not so easy to explain.

A stack trace of the original NPE tomcat logged when you had problems would be helpful. (I'm c3p0's developer.)

Note that c3p0.properties needs to be at the top level of the CLASSPATH of your app, which may not be where other config files are located. c3p0.properties is loaded as a ClassLoader resource.

Answer (score 0):

The bug can be fixed using commercial pooling libraries as suggested above. I used c3p0 exactly as suggested by @NayanWadekar.
Please note that c3p0 is dependent on SLF4J. So after including the c3p0 jars in your classpath, you also have to add SLF4J jars in your classpath. The trick about this thing is that, if those SLF4J jars are not present, the compiler still won't complain, you only get errors after deploying the app. 
Also, if you are using Netbeans, avoid creating an SLF4J library from all the jars bundled together [here](http://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.6.4.zip) at slf4.org. The reason being that some of the jars are not meant to be used together in the same project. Just use the following two jars alone from the library: slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar and slf4j-jdk14-1.6.4.jar. You can visit [www.slf4j.org](http://www.slf4j.org) for details.