# Hibernate and mysql timeout issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have been having trouble with Hibernate and Mysql timeout error.I am also using properties of c3p0(connection provider). After my Hibernate/MySQL have been running after 8 hours(which is default timeout value in Mysql), I have the exception. But it doesn't help.

property for auto reconnect also not working.

Here is my Hibernate Configuration:

```
<property name="connection_provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    **<property name="connection.autoReconnect"> true</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>**
    <property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>
    <property name="c3p0.validate">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">20</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">40</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">10</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxPoolSize">100</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxIdleTime">300</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxStatements">50</property>
    <property name="c3p0.minPoolSize">10</property>
    <property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/doqeap</property>
    <property name="connection.user">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">*******</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</property>
    <mapping></mapping>
```

please help me to sort out this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Rahul, the 8 hrs timeout you mentioned is for what ? Query timeout (which I hope not) or idle connection timeout ?

Comment: Santosh, if we don't interact 8 hours with mysql than mysql automatic close connection.Default wait_timeout and interactive_timeout of mysql is 28800 seconds equals 8 hours

Comment: Similar one, can refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/10695028/366964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Connection timeout is the issue, then Connection testing should eliminate, wither via tests on checkout (reliable but imposes a client visible performance cost) or tests on checking + idle tests.

Looking at you config params, it looks like you mean to set tests on checkouts and idle tests.  I'd expect that c3p0 would eliminate timed out Exceptions before your app saw them. If that hasn't happened, it'd be interesting to see two things: 1) c3p0's config, which gets logged at INFO when the pool is initialized -- is c3p0, through the hibernate layer, seeing the configuration you intend? 2) the Exception that your app receives when it encounters the stale Connections.

Good luck!