# Hibernate 4 default transaction timeout value

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, timeout

I'm getting this error:

```
2014-11-14 17:39:44 [WARN]SqlExceptionHelper:143    SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2014-11-14 17:39:44 [ERROR]SqlExceptionHelper:144   Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2014-11-14 17:39:44 [ERROR]BackupService:245    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
```

Seems that Hibernate has a small transaction timeout for my job, but I can not find what is the default timeout value. I did not find it also in hibernate documentation, I find how to change it, but not the default value.

This is my hibernate configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.test.db.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>             
                <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>         
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Do you know what is the default timeout value for an hibernate transaction with this configuration?

Comment: What is ur connection string ? You haven't specify `hibernate.connection.url` property in `hibernateProperties`.

Comment: It is not about the transaction. At the end of the last error line, it says `Could not open connection`.

Comment: Have you tried to start your database in server mode ? Is it able to start ?

Comment: Yes, it works, just at the end of an operation that takes about 5minutes it brokes. Maybe it is because the main (5 minutes) method has @Transaction annotation?

Comment: I underline that the application well works, just this operation has this trouble EVERY time I run it.

Comment: Why u r using **two different dialects in same bean sessionFactory** `<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>` & `<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>` ?

Comment: This is a typo, I'm using mysql dialect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same exception. I googled and found your question without answer :)

I changed "Timeout Seconds:" from 300 to 1000 (possible to increase more, it depends on your transaction timeout) on "mydomain->Configuration->JTA" on Weblogic Console or increase JTA timeout on your application server.

Then, for hibernate.cfg.xml you may check this answer: [Hibernate/MySQL Connection Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695028/hibernate-mysql-connection-timeout)

It works.