# Java/jersey Web services needs to restart(error code 500)

Tags: apache, web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am developing REST web service using  Java, jersey, Apache tomcat eclipse.
Every thing seems to work fine till I shut sown my system and go home. Web services are deployed on a server. when i try to access web services next day(after inactivity of 10-12 hours), Server returns 500 error. Once i restart tomcat, everything start working again. Am I missing some configuration?

**Hibernate config**

```
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XYZ</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">aa</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">aa </property>  


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>XYZ</display-name>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
 <param-value>com.xyz.services</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
<param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter;com.xyz.services.CrossDomainFilter</param-value>
</init-param>


 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Stacktrace:

```
: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
Apr 13, 2015 12:49:21 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Apr 13, 2015 12:49:21 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:217)
    at com.stayprime.services.DBConnection.checkLogin(DBConnection.java:1741)
    at com.stayprime.services.DBConnection.getUser(DBConnection.java:773)
    at com.stayprime.services.UserManagement.getUser(UserManagement.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:211)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1225)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4568)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:163)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 60,162,060 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 60,162,060 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3661)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:402)
    at com.stayprime.services.DBConnection.checkLogin(DBConnection.java:1730)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3643)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: @peeskillet  Log added.

Comment: Looks like a database problem, not a Jersey problem. Look at the "Caused by:..."

Comment: Hi @Kamal, did you solve the issue, i'm also having same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL State 08003 sugests that the "connection does not exist".

Probably you have a bad configuration in the hibernate (a timeout or something)

Check it please!

Comment: Added the hibernate config content. I haven't written any time out etc. Is it set by default? and where?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695028/hibernate-mysql-connection-timeout

Comment: you try it? it results?

Comment: Yes I have implemented it. Just waiting for 8 hour of inactivity. :)

Comment: Ok. if results please say me.

Comment: Hi Kamal, did you solve the issue, i'm also having same issue.

Comment: @ramesh6233   Yes, check the link in comment by joao.

Comment: ramesh6233, if this solution works please vote them... Thanks in advance